# PHPSpec and Laravel

Tags: php, testing, laravel, bdd, phpspec

**What is the point in using PHPSpec if I cant access or use any Eloquent methods?**

For example: ($this reffers to an Eloquent `Product` model)

```
function it_removes_property(PropertyValueInterface $property)
{        
    $this->addProperty($property);
    $this->properties->shouldHaveCount(1);

    $this->removeProperty($property);
    $this->properties->shouldHaveCount(0);
}
```

This will not work as within the methods `addProperty` and `removeProperty` there are calls to various Eloquent Collection and Model functions, it seems PHPSpec cant handle this, even when all these classes are included with `use` statements.

I noticed in Jeffery Way's screen casts on Laracasts he never uses a real Eloquent model. He only uses vanilla PHP objects. Whats the point of that? Thats not the real world.

*Also this has nothing to do with referencing the eloquent model class correctly as I'm already doing this `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`*

*Also I NEVER NEVER EVER use facades. So its not that either.*

Answer (score 3):

PHPSpec is not capable of doing a lot of things you can, for example, do with PHPUnit and Mockery.
*Bottom line: I'd say PHPSpec is not the right tool for testing Eloquent.*

There is a lot of *'magic'* happening inside Eloquent and PHPSpec doesn't seem to like magic, if you feels like you must use PHPSpec for testing Eloquent or the world will shatter then here are a couple things you can do.

**Disclaimer:** *I am not encouraging you to go ahead and use PHPSpec for Eloquent testing, in fact I don't want you to test eloquent models with it, I am only explaining some tricks to work around the situations you will encounter while testing magic methods and black art - in a hope that you will be able to apply them somewhere else when it make sense. To me, it doesn't make sense in case of Eloquent models.*

So here is the list:

- Don't use magic getters and setters, use `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` instead
- Don't use magic calls to lazily loaded relations, i.e. `$user->profile`. Use methods `$user->profile()->getResults()`
- Create a SUT mock class extending your model and define those `where` methods on it, also define the scope methods and everything else that Eloquent is supposed to do for you 'magically'.
- Use `beAnInstanceOf()` method to switch to the mock and make assertions on it.

Here is an example of how my test would look like:

**Product Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;    

class Product extends Model
{
    public function scopeLatest($query)
    {
        return $query->where('created_at', '>', new Carbon('-1 week'))
            ->latest();
    }

    // Model relations here...
}
```

**Spec for Product Model**

```
<?php namespace Spec\Model;

use Prophecy\Argument;
use App\Entities\Product;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;

class ProductSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    public function let()
    {
        $this->beAnInstanceOf(DecoyProduct::class);
    }

    public function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('Product');
    }
}

// Decoy Product to run tests on
class DecoyProduct extends Product
{
    public function where();

    // Assuming the Product model has a scope method
    // 'scopeLatest' on it that'd translate to 'latest()'
    public function latest();

    // add other methods similarly
}
```

By defining the `where` and `latest` method on the decoy class and making it SUT you are letting PHPSpec know that those methods actually exists on the class. Their arguments and return type doesn't matter, only the existence.

Advantage ?
Now in your spec when you call `->where()` or `->latest()` method on the model PHPSpec will not complain about it, and you can change the methods on decoy class to return, say, an object of `Prophecy` and make assertions on it.